# Issue on SQL Insert Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert

I encountered an error "Number of Query values and destination fields are not the same" in MS ACCESS Database

Here are my Queries:

I named this QryMetrics

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F
FROM (SELECT count(ID ) as A FROM RelevantResults WHERE Field1 Is Not Null and Field1 <> Chr(13) & Chr(10))  AS Q1,
(SELECT count(ID) as B FROM RelevantResults WHERE Field2 Is Not Null)  AS Q2, 
(SELECT COUNT(ID) as C FROM RelevantResults WHERE Field3 Like '*.jpg' AND Field1 Is Not Null)  AS Q3, 
(SELECT COUNT(ID) as D FROM RelevantResults WHERE Field3 Like '*.jpg' OR Field1 Is Not Null)  AS Q4,
(SELECT COUNT(ID) as E FROM RelevantResults WHERE Field3 Like '*.jpg' OR Field1 Is Not Null OR Field2 Is Not Null)  AS Q5,
(SELECT COUNT(ID) as F FROM RelevantResults WHERE Field3 Like '*.jpg')  AS Q6;
```

Insert Query:

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO metrics (Filename, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6)
Select '" & strFile & "', QryMetrics.* from QryMetrics;"
```

I'm executing the Insert query using DoCmd.RunSQL in VB.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
```

When I'm trying to run a query in the database just for the 6 fields:
I encountered an error: 
The Insert into statement contains the following unknown field name: 'A'

```
INSERT INTO metrics (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6)
select  * from qryMetrics
```

Any thoughts on this? Thanks

Comment: Looks fine. The thing that confuses me is the `'" & strFile & "'` part. Shouldn't that be `"'" & strFile & "'"` instead?

Comment: It works fine in my VB. I'm passing a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my Problem:

```
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO metrics (Filename, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6)
Select '" & strFile & "', A, B, C, D, E, F from QryMetrics;"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
INSERT INTO metrics (Filenae, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6)
Select '" & strFile & "',     -- 1 column
        QryMetrics.*          -- + 6 from QryMetrix
from QryMetrics;              -- = 7 in total
```

Column list in insert has 6 columns (field1, field2, ... field6),
but your select returs 7 columns.

Comment: No, It has 7 including filename + 6 fields